# No Executor button in Notebook files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

looking to schedule a notebook file but there is no executor button. Anyone seen this before? No matter which notebook file I open there is no button, see below:

[Jupyter Notebook Buttons Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfXt6.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.