# Vertex AI Does not Allow you To Schedule Via Executor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

Documentation on Google Cloud mentions being able to schedule jobs/notebooks via the "Executor" Button in Vertex AI.

Doc:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/schedule-and-execute-notebooks-with-vertex-ai-workbench?_ga=2.262871372.-1591247165.1668649415

UI in Doc:
[image]

MyUI

[image]

Looking for a reason why this button is missing.

Duplicate of this question:
[No Executor button in Notebook files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151464/no-executor-button-in-notebook-files)

Comment: Which notebook are you using?

Comment: One that I added

Comment: According to this [gcp documents](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/release-notes#April_06_2022), the executor is available only for managed notebooks. From the screenshots it looks like you are using User-Managed Notebooks. Can you clarify your question by adding some details about your requirements?