# Running Jupyter Notebook in GCP on a Schedule

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

What is the best way to migrate a jupyter notebook in to Google Cloud Platform?

Requirements

- I don't want to do a lot of changes to the notebook to get it to run
- I want it to be scheduleable, preferably through the UI
- I want it to be able to run a ipynb file, not a py file
- In AWS it seems like sagemaker is the no brainer solution for this. I want the tool in GCP that gets as close to the specific task without a lot of extras

I've tried the following,

- Cloud Function: it seems like it's best for running python scripts, not a notebook, requires you to run a `main.py` file by default
- Dataproc: seems like you can add a notebook to a running instance but it cannot be scheduled
- Dataflow: sort of seemed like overkill, like it wasn't the best tool and that it was better suited apache based tools

I feel like this question should be easier, I found this article on the subject:

[How to Deploy and Schedule Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud Platform](https://medium.com/bliblidotcom-techblog/how-to-deploy-and-schedule-jupyter-notebook-on-google-cloud-18a7ca23b463)

He actually doesn't do what the title says, he moves a lot of GCP code in to a main.py to create an instance and he has the instance execute the notebook.

Feel free to correct my perspective on any of this

Comment: For anyone trying to do the same, it made more sense just to convert to a script for my use case

Answer (score 1):

I use [Vertex AI Workbench](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/introduction) to run notebooks on GCP. It provides two variants:

- Managed Notebooks
- User-managed Notebooks

[User-managed notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/introduction) creates compute instances at the background and it comes with [pre-built packages](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/introduction#preinstalled_software) such as Jupyter Lab, Python, etc and allows customisation. I mainly use for developing Dataflow pipelines.

Other requirement of scheduling - [Managed Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/introduction) supports this feature, [refer this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/introduction#executor) (I am yet to try Managed Notebooks):

> Use the executor to run a notebook file as a one-time execution or on
> a schedule. Choose the specific environment and hardware that you want
> your execution to run on. Your notebook's code will run on Vertex AI
> custom training, which can make it easier to do distributed training,
> optimize hyperparameters, or schedule continuous training jobs. See
> Run notebook files with the executor.
>
> You can use parameters in your execution to make specific changes to
> each run. For example, you might specify a different dataset to use,
> change the learning rate on your model, or change the version of the
> model.
>
> You can also set a notebook to run on a recurring schedule. Even while
> your instance is shut down, Vertex AI Workbench will run your notebook
> file and save the results for you to look at and share with others.

Comment: It seems like the scheduling/executor only works for managed notebooks vvv. Can you schedule notebooks in dataflow ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513285/vertex-ai-does-not-allow-you-to-schedule-via-executor?noredirect=1#comment131568976_74513285